# Couldn't upgrade OpenSSL from 1.1.1f to 3.x

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, openssl

I am trying to upgrade my OpenSSL from 1.1.1f to >=3.0 (specifically >=3.0.8), so I simply try to get the latest version by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

I am sure OpenSSL latest versions are 3.x from what I see [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/):

However, this is what I get after my attempt:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 472 not upgraded.
```

I know I could install the package manually as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565653/12859025) but I try to avoid it because it might leave consequences that I cannot fix.

Is there any other way to upgrade OpenSSL without affecting other part of my system?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running Ubuntu 20.04; the latest `openssl` package available there [is 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/openssl).

If you want to upgrade `openssl` because you’re concerned about security vulnerabilities, you shouldn’t be worried: the Ubuntu package receives security updates, and [CVEs are tracked and addressed](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves?q=&package=openssl&priority=&version=focal&status=) regardless of the level of upstream support available.

If you want to upgrade because you need new features, then you should either [upgrade to 22.04, which has 3.0.8](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lunar/+source/openssl), or build the latest version yourself.

Comment: Yes, I am using ubuntu 20.04. I  want to upgrade `openssl` because it seems like an sdk I want use is expecting 3.0.8. However, if can I want to keep using 20.04 because our product is deployed using this ubuntu version.

Comment: @znyi It seems you need one development system and one test deployment system.  These (or one of them) should be able to be virtual machines on the same hardware.

Comment: @znyi or just use a container for development, like `docker` or `singularity`.